# Discord.js, Message not defined error, any solutions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**Hello everyone**, I'm learning to code on discord.js so you may find multiple errors in my code (feel free to correct) which I have pieced together from various sources. Right now this is the error I'm facing : **ReferenceError: message is not defined**

**Here is the code :**

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs')
const token = 'no token ;)';
let reports = require("./reports.json"); 
const filter = (reaction, user) => { 
    return reaction.emoji.name === ':white_check_mark:' 
};

if(!reports[message.author.id]){
    reports[message.author.id] = {
        reports: 0
  };
}

message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 4, time: 6000, errors: ['time'] }) 

.then(reports[message.author.id].reports =  reports[message.author.id] + 1);


fs.writeFile("./reports.json", JSON.stringify(reports), (err) =>{
    if (err) console.log (err)
});



bot.on('ready', () =>{
    Console.log('Bot has Awoken');
})


bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you need to have them inside the [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) event like so:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    let reports = require("./reports.json");
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return reaction.emoji.name === ':white_check_mark:'
    };

    if (!reports[message.author.id]) {
        reports[message.author.id] = {
            reports: 0
        };
    }

    message.awaitReactions(filter, {
        max: 4,
        time: 6000,
        errors: ['time']
    })
    .then(reports[message.author.id].reports = reports[message.author.id] + 1);

    fs.writeFile("./reports.json", JSON.stringify(reports), (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
    });
})
```